# Unable to receive push notification through expo-notifications in production apk build Android

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, eas

The expo push notifications through Firebase configuration were working well for the last 6 months until 2 weeks ago, the production build stopped receiving any notifications. On further analysis of this issue, I found that the exponent push token was not being generated by the getExpoPushTokenAsync() method for the android platform alone. IOS still works fine.

I found this question on stack overflow
[Unable to receive push notification through expo-notifications in production build Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766468/unable-to-receive-push-notification-through-expo-notifications-in-production-bui)
but I don't know where in the build.gradle file o add the line
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2'`
I tried adding it in different places but when added the build kept on crashing
but without this line the build is sucsessfull
I'm building the app with `eas build  --profile=preview --local`

log when crashing

```
[RUN_GRADLEW] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * What went wrong:
[RUN_GRADLEW] Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
[RUN_GRADLEW]    > Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zza found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzd found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zze found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzf found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzg found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzh found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver found in modules jetified-firebase-iid-17.0.2-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2) and jetified-firebase-messaging-22.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0)
[RUN_GRADLEW]      
[RUN_GRADLEW]      Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Try:
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[RUN_GRADLEW] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[RUN_GRADLEW] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[RUN_GRADLEW] BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s
[RUN_GRADLEW] Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.

Build failed
Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.
    Error: npx exited with non-zero code: 1
```

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --tunnel",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "expo-modules-autolinking": "~0.8.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "expo": "^45.0.3",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.2.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-tracking-transparency": "~2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-multi-selectbox": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.0.2",
    "react-native-side-menu-updated": "^1.3.2",
    "undefined": "@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.67.6",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true,
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.0.14"
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "snack-3c1f5426-6618-428a-b011-1321c650ca86",
    "version": "1.0.14",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.package.name",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.14"
    },
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "NOTIFICATIONS"
      ],
      "versionCode": 14,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.package.name",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyBcVpwhaufOshzagukYg5RGhuj7Zs4djXk"
        }
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "description": "",
    "plugins": [
      
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-notifications",
      {
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "color": "#ffffff",
        "sounds": [
          "./local/assets/notification-sound.mp3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

eas.json

```
{
    "cli": {
      "version": ">= 0.34.0"
    },
    "build": {
      "development": {
        "developmentClient": true,
        "distribution": "internal",
        "env": { "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/usr/lib/android-sdk" }
      },
      "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "android": {
          "buildType": "apk"
        },
        "env": { "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/usr/lib/android-sdk" }
      },
      "production": {
        "releaseChannel": "production",
        "env": {
          "APP_ENV": "production",
          "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT": "/usr/lib/android-sdk"
        }
      }
    },  
    "submit": {
      "development": {
        "android": {
          "serviceAccountKeyPath": "../path/to/api-xxx-yyy-zzz.json",
          "track": "internal"
        },
        "ios": {
          "appleId": "<My_Apple_Id>",
          "ascAppId": "1000000000",
          "appleTeamId": "appleIdTeam",
          "companyName":"Company Name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```